# PHP date incrementing error

Tags: php, date, increment

I am trying to create a calendar where the date increments and each date is clickable, which links to a search. The strange part is that the date stops at `25th October`, and stops incrementing. i.e `24th, 25th, 25th, 25th...`

Its doesn't matter which day the calendar started with (been staring at it for a few days), but at `25th it stops incrementing`.

Grateful for any advice.(The 2nd part after the gap is probably irrelevant, but including it in case there could be any link)

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++){ 
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date) + 86400);
    array_push($array_date, $date);
    $separatedate = explode('-', $date);   
    $getday = date("l", strtotime($date));
    print "<button class='submitsearch btn' value=$array_date[$i]>" . ltrim($separatedate[0], '0') . "<br>" . $getday . "<br></button>";

    if (!checkdate($separatedate[1] , $separatedate[0]+1 , $separatedate[2])) {
        $nextmonth = date("F", strtotime($date) + 86400);
       print "<strong>". $nextmonth . "</strong><hr/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date) + 86400);
```

You appear to be relying on that to increment the date. Usually, that will be fine... but it isn't when we have a 25 hour day, due to daylight saving time changes.

I suggest you use date/time arithmetic functions (e.g. [`date_add`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php)) designed to add a day, rather than adding 24 hours. Or make sure *all* arithmetic is done in UTC, which won't have any time zone changes. In general, I would try to avoid performing any more string conversions than you really need to: keep a variable representing the date/time in an idiomatic way, and perform arithmetic on that - then just *format* that variable when you need to. I don't see any need to call `strtotime` anywhere, if you do this right.

Comment: Or just use `strtotime($date." + 1 day")`

Comment: @BenPearlKahan: Possibly, but I'd generally advise removing string conversions from the mix when they're just not needed. Formatting and parsing like this is a really bad idea, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Jon! And Ben for contributing. Giving Jon the credit for pointing out the issue. For those who want to know the final solution implemented I replaced the troubled line with creating a new DateTime object: $date = new DateTime($date); $date->(new DateInterval('P1D'); $date = $date->format('d-m-Y'); for integration with the rest of the code :)